# Stack but one of the elements should use Expanded ()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a container that should take up all available Space in width thats possible. However, I need to position an element on it that clips out of it, so I am using a Stack for it.

Using an Expanded on the lower stacked element causes an exception and also using a stack just with the positioned Item also causes an exception because the stacked widget has nowhere to anchor to.
Any Ideas how to solve this?

double.maxFinite as width does not work either

Using an expanded around the Containers looks like this:
[image]

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // Padding for content to Container Border
                child: Text("Fruit"),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -8,
              left: 10,
              child: Container(
                //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), // Padding for content to Container Border
                  child: Text("Fruit"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // Padding for content to Container Border
                  child: Text("Fruit"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -8,
              left: 10,
              child: Container(
                //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), // Padding for content to Container Border
                  child: Text("Fruit"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: can you put your code here ?

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: do you want to make width of child container like the parent container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fit: StackFit.expand,`

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: _card()),
          Expanded(child: _card()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _card() {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text("Fruit"),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: -8,
          left: 10,
          child: Container(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 5),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Text("Fruit"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```